# Duplicate file SEO Friendly using htaccess

Tags: seo, canonical-link

I have the follow doubt . I 've created a SEO Friendly file using the rewriterule of .htaccess. But now i have in the same directory

Original File

File created with htaccess

So I have duplicate file, i cannot use rel tag canonical because if i put it in the Orifinal File i find it also in the file create. How can i resolve? I think that i can stop file with robots.txt or i can block the spider using htacess, Is this the right solution? Now my htaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /macchine/listino/
RewriteRule marca-auto-(.*)\.htm$ marca.php?auto=$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule vis-marca-(.*)-ide-(.*)\.htm$ vis.php?marca=$1&ide=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is simple create rel canonical

```
<link rel="canonical" href="your-new-url" />
```

This rel canonical can be places in 2 urls of your site (original and rewrited).

However in this case probably the best method will be creating 301 redirect from "original url" to rewrited. In this case even if you have any links to original urls, the linkjuice will be redirected to rewrited urls.

Comment: About canonical , it is the easy solution but in the tutorial of google (Italia) i read that i must use it in duplicate file, not in original... i have also asked.   I am using hostagator  i 've tried with [L,R=301] but nothing the url goes to a error 404 page, i think  because the htaccess is on the sub directory mysite.com/macchine/listino/ that  must  i put Rewritebase?  I am studing to understand just now.

Comment: You can use rel canonical at original page - look at `http://moz.com/blog/rel-confused-answers-to-your-rel-canonical-questions`. And 301 you can make also in PHP checking value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - if it starts with `marca.php?auto=` you can simple do 301 redirection

Comment: sincerely i've already thinked to a solution with the PHP also for the tag rel canonical, ok moz says you can do it, here in forum google.it says don't put it in the right(canonical) file.... i use php and i resolve,  But i don't understand why if i write the url of URL SEO Friendly goes to the old file with ?marca=Audi and not the opposite. I've many confusion....why if write the ?marca.php=Audi don't goes to marca-auto-Audi.htm?

Comment: You completely changed your `.htaccess` and I don't understand why. Why you added there 301 redirection? Now it doesn't make sense. Previous was ok and you had to only add redirection in PHP from old urls to new ones or use canonical urls

Comment: i've a little confusion, i 'm trying many solutions. I want that when from index.php on /macchine/listino/  click on  ?marca=Audi goes to url friendly  marca-auto-Audi.htm , so i decide to put the flag R 301 to do redirect and to pass PR , but with the rule up , i don't obtain the result, where is my mystake?